# Why does Java stack Optionals?

Tags: java, option-type, language-design

*I'm generally very happy with the design of the Java language but today I came across a strange design choice.
I don't know any platform where you can suggest changes to the Java language for version 9 or 10 and therefore I'm writing this issue here.*

---

With Optionals you have a much better control over the behaviour if a value is `null`.

Today I mapped a value in a stream to an `Optional`.
I was really surprised, that `findFirst` then gives me a `Optional<Optional<T>>` instead of just `Optional<T>`.

**Where is the point in having `Optional<Optional<T>>`?**

For Java 9 and Streams this is solved with `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` but this is only a work around and boilerplate code.

**Wouldn't it be much better if Optionals generally wouldn't stack and always flats down?**

```
Optional<Optional<T>> => Optional<T>
Optional.of(Optional.of("")) => Optional.of("")
```

---

Further explanation:

Working with Optionals you don't care if the sub optional was null or if the actual object was `null`. It always would come down to `Optional.empty()`.

```
String s = null;
Optional<String> opt = null;
Optional.of(s) => Optional.empty()
Optional.of(opt) => Optional.empty()
```

Also if you are working with optionals you are only interested in the object. So if you try to get the object you always have to double get and check the optional.

```
if(optionalOfOptional.isPresent()) {
    optional = optionalOfOptional.get();
    if(optional.isPresent()) {
        objectOfInterest = optional.get();
    }
}
```

I even see this being a source for errors since you would always need to check both optionals if you condition on your object being present.

```
if(optionalOfOptional.isPresent() && optionalOfOptional.get().isPresent()) {
    ...
}
```

Only checking the first optional could easily lead to mistakes.

In addition, why would it make sense to have a Optional that is `null` in the first place? Isn't optional there to get rid of working with `null`?

---

On the method level this could be solved for sure.

For example `Optional.of` could look something like:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value) {
    return value instanceof Optional ? value : new Optional<>(value);
}
```

On the type level this is probably not that easy.

Comment: good description but your question _Wouldn't it be much better if Optionals generally wouldn't stack and always flats down?_ is opinion based.

Comment: The second transformation would be possible if the `Optional.of` method used an instanceof check, but I don't think it is possible to automatically perform the second, type-level transformation with java generics.

Comment: How would this be done? There's no way to automatically flatten `Optional<Optional<T>>` to `Optional<T>`. The type system can't do it. It's not a design choice because there's no alternative.

Comment: There's nothing special about `Optional` with regard to generics; and would you want a `List<List<T>>` to become a `List<T>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner No, of course not, because every List entry would be a List. This is totally different from an Optional where it always comes down to the Object being present or not.

Comment: But an `Optional<T>` object can itself be `null` or its content can be `null` (absent). How would you differentiate between the two if `Optional<Optional<T>>` didn't exist?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou This should never happen. Then your code has a code smell.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question to show why you might reasonably want to map an object to `Optional` in the middle of a stream operation in the first place?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou If you generally return Optionals from methods (instead of null) in your code and you include such a method in your stream than you will get this situation. For sure no one would do a Optional.of() in a stream mapping. That is not the situation ;)

Comment: This sort of question is generally not useful without a concrete use case. Sure, `Optional<Optional<T>>` is hard to understand; but what are you doing in your stream processing that results in elements of this type? Could there be a better way to do the processing you want without ending up with this type? We can't tell, unless you provide an example.

Comment: There are many combinations of library classes that don't make sense; for example, its impossible to simultaneously implement the contracts of `List` and `Set`. But, since the compiler can't read the library documentation (and shouldn't), it doesn't know this, so won't try to stop you from implementing both. Similarly, `Optional<T>` is a generic type, and you can instantiate with your choice of `T`.  So we can't prevent `Optional<Optional<T>>`, even if it is silly.  I think your objection comes down to "I wish `Optional` were a language feature, not a library"?  OK, but it _is_ just a library.

Answer (score 5):

It simply doesn't make sense to forbid `Optional<Optional<T>>`.

Let's say you've got a `List<Optional<T>>`. The following lists are different:

```
List<Optional<T>> listA = Arrays.asList(Optional.empty());
List<Optional<T>> listB = Arrays.asList();
```

They're obviously different: the first is non-empty, the second is empty.

Correspondingly, the result of invoking `findFirst()` on their streams is different:

```
System.out.println(listA.stream().findFirst().isPresent()); // true
System.out.println(listB.stream().findFirst().isPresent()); // false
```

Now, I know about the meaning of the data in those lists that Java can't possibly know. Let's say that the lists contain the results of invoking a list of `Callable<Optional<T>>`s. In that case, there *might be* an important difference to my application between:

- I invoked N>0 callables, and all of them returned `Optional.empty()`
- I invoked zero callables.

So I really don't want the language or API to assume that there's no difference between the two, and converting the `Optional<Optional<T>>` to an `Optional<T>`.

And since a `List<E>.stream().findFirst()` *always* returns an `Optional<E>`, there's no way to prevent an `Optional<Optional<T>>` without preventing me creating a `List<Optional<T>>` (or `Collection`, `Set`, `HashMap<K, Optional<T>>` etc). So, you'd basically have to completely disallow nested generics, which would be a major loss of functionality.

I'm quite contented with the existence of `Optional<Optional<T>>`, as it is entirely consistent with the rest of the language. If you don't like them, just avoid creating them; but don't think that's right for everybody else.

Comment: I see your point in having a nested optional is consistent with the rest of the language. I argue that it logically and practically isn't the right behaviour for Optional. At the end of the day we want the language that we work with to be efficient (in terms of time we spend programming) and readable. For example it would make much more sense if a nested optional would return false for isPresent if the sub object isn't even the nested optional is. Sure no one wants nested behaviour to be removed on other objects. Just for Optionals it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It logically and practically isn't what **you** want from Optional. Don't assume that nobody else wants it just because you don't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to offend you. I changed my wording :)

Answer (score 1):

I talk about this elsewhere that [an `Optional<T>` should never be null.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089405/1541137) It violates what `Optional<T>` promises: getting rid of `NullPointerException`s.

**Therefore**, I think it is a deficient design in the Optional API to allow `Optional<Optional<T>>`. The methods to get instances of Optional should behave better when given an Optional. But that being said, they can't. They could be accomplished if Optional.of was overloaded except for one slight issue.

Since you can have a generic type T that is of type Optional, you can't have two Optional.of methods (one for Optional and one for T). Occasionally it would prevent some code from compiling if someone had the bright idea to have an `Optional<Optional<T>>`. Take the below code, it will fail to compile.

```
package otherCode;

public class Abc<T> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc<B> test1 = new Abc<>();
        test1.foo(new A());
        test1.foo(new B());

        Abc<Base> test2 = new Abc<>();
        test2.foo(new A());
        test2.foo(new B());

        Abc<A> test3 = new Abc<>();
        // these two don't compile
        test3.foo(new A());
        test3.foo(new B());
    }

    public void foo(A item) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }

    public void foo(T item) {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public static class Base {
    }

    public static class A extends Base {

    }

    public static class B extends Base {

    }
}
```

Without forcing a language and syntax change on the entire language (forbidding a `Optional<Optional<T>>`) the automatic conversion is not an easy task.

Java 8 in general I found took developers a while to grasp. When it first came out, I'd see `Map<String, Optional<T>>` when `Map<String, T>` would have sufficed or I did see `Optional<Optional<T>>`. I even saw `Map<Optional<T>, Optional<Set<Optional<T>>>>` instead of simply `Map<T, Set<T>>`. As time progressed and people grappled with the language, I feel we learned to better manage these typing and get more sensible typing.

I think it is unfortunate Java doesn't do the conversion automatically but for the poor soul who may need an `Optional<Optional<T>>` one day, **I'm willing to use map, flatMap, orElse, and ofNullable every once in awhile to keep my typing sane.** Using those methods may help with your particular quandaries.

**Edit:**

I see, either missed it or an edit, that OP saw that `Stream<Optional<T>>.first` returns an `Optional<Optional<T>>`. What OP intends to do affects a compromise. They could .map the stream to strip the interior Optional or they could .filter & .map the stream to strip out empty Optionals. One sad, extra line of code.

Comment: "I think it is a deficient design in the Optional API to allow Optional<Optional<T>>" So how would you have designed the Optional API disallow it? You say "without forcing a language change", but what *specific* language change do you propose? `Optional` isn't defined in the language - there is no special case for it in the type system; and the type system is already plenty complicated enough without introducing such special cases for a valid use case.

Comment: @AndyTurner my apologies. That is mostly my point. The type system is hella complicated and the only way to 'fix' OP's issue would be to make it even more so by promoting these corner cases up into the language.